# Excel: SUMPRODUCT with percentages

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I use the following formula to calculate the SUMPRODUCT of the values in a column with the condition that there is a match between B2:B6 and A1:A3 (shoutout to user:8162520).

`=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$B$6=$A$9)*(G2:G6))`

Now however I would like to subtract to that result the percentage in C1 and/or D1, and "give it" to one of the other blue numbers, again with the condition that there is a match between C2:C6 or D2:D6 and A7:A9.

So for example in G7 the result for "1" should be 50% of 10 + 75% of 5, because "2" takes 50% of 10(G2) and "3" takes 25% of 5(G5).

The point is to create an overview of how many hours employees (1,2,3) have to spend spend on project B2:B6 for each week (E,F,G), and what happens if other employees take a certain percentage of the workload (C,D). What is the most efficient way to do this?

[image]

The numbers in A, B,C, D are reference numbers, they should not be part of the calculation. Maybe it's clearer if I use letters. See also the right results for E7:G7. The outcome must be the sum of the values in each column (workload) minus the percentage in C and D IF there is someone sharing the workload:

[image]

Comment: "C1 or D2" OR C1 or D1 ?

Comment: Sorry, you're right: C1 and/or D1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So deducting the percentage in C1:D1, presumably where there is no workload the result should be zero?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$6=$A7)*($C$2:$D$6<>"")*(1-$C$1:$D$1)*G$2:G$6)
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution @Dave, but I think I didn't explain myself well enough. The outcome is not correct. Maybe it's clearer if I use letters (see the new image) and give the desired outome.