# Excel: SUMPRODUCT calculating shared workload in hours with percentages

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I'm gonna re-ask a question ([Excel: SUMPRODUCT with percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080332/excel-sumproduct-with-percentages)) that didn't get solved in another way:

I'm trying to calculate the workload/hours for each employee for certain projects. In column B you can see the responsible (100% of the workload), in C you can see which employee is taking 50% of the workload off the responsible employee. So I need the sum of all hours, while deducing of adding the 50% in case the workload is shared and giving it to the employee helping.

My current formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$6=$A7)*($C$2:$D$6<>"")*(1-$C$1:$D$1)*E2:E6)`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A6=$B$2:$B$5)*($B$1-$C$1*(""<>$C$2:$C$5))*D$2:D$5+($A6=$C$2:$C$5)*$C$1*D$2:D$5)
```

[image]

Comment: I think this solution works best, because it could be useful to add another % option. What if I added a column with 25%?

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `D6`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$C$5=$A6)*D$2:D$5/MMULT(--($B$2:$C$5<>""),{1;1}))
```

Drag right and down.

Comment: Wonderfully crafted Sir, the `MMULT` really made the difference !

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with an array formula using SUMPRODUCT

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$5=$A8)*IF($C$2:$C$5="";D$2:D$5;D$2:D$5/2))+SUMPRODUCT(--($C$2:$C$5=$A8)*D$2:D$5)*0,5
```

Because it's an array formula, it must be entered pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: I think there is an IF in Spanish in there right (SI)? ````=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$5=$A8)*IF($C$2:$C$5="";D$2:D$5;D$2:D$5/2))+SUMPRODUCT(--($C$2:$C$5=$A8)*D$2:D$5)*0,5````

Comment: @Johanna You are right, I forgot the translation. Updated!

Comment: Whenever you use `IF()` you need to CSE-enter a formula pre-ms365. Therefor you could also just use `SUM()` instead of `SUMPRODUCT()`. Saves a few characters =)