# Excel: SUMPRODUCT calculating shared workload in hours with multiple percentages

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

This is the same problem as ([Excel: SUMPRODUCT calculating shared workload in hours with percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71111082/excel-sumproduct-calculating-shared-workload-in-hours-with-percentages)) with an addition.

I'm trying to calculate the workload/hours for each employee for certain projects. In column B you can see the responsible (100% of the workload), in C you can see which employee is taking 50% or 25% of the workload off the responsible employee. So I need the sum of all hours, while deducing of adding the 50% or 25% in case the workload is shared and giving it to the employee helping.

The latest formula adding/subtracting only the 50% in C:

`=SOMPRODUCT(($A6=$B$2:$B$5)*($B$1-$C$1*(""<>$C$2:$C$5))*E$2:E$5+($A6=$C$2:$C$5)*$C$1*E$2:E$5)`

What would be the most elegant solution? I need the option to change the percentage.

[image]

```
100%        50%     25%         Day 1   Day 2   Day 3
Project 1   Mark    Peter       6       2        6
Project 2   Peter   Lily        2       8        2
Project 3   Peter   Lily        0       4        8
Project 4   Lily    Mark        4       0        2
Mark                            8       2        7
Peter                           1       8        9
Lily                            3       4        2
```

Comment: So change the percentages in b1, c1 or d1.

Comment: That would change all the other results. I want to be able to see which employee is overburdened and what happens if one of the others jumps in and takes of a percentage of the workload. So the point is to include an extra percentage (D1) without changing the other two. And of course make the formula as efficient/short as possible.

Comment: So you have a solution that needs editing, how would you change it?

Comment: Well if I knew I wouldn't ask... I managed to add the 25% in D by editing the last part of the formula ```=SOMPRODUCT(($A7=$B$2:$B$5)*($B$1-$C$1*(""<>$C$2:$C$5))*G$2:G$5+($A7=$C$2:$C$5)*$C$1*G$2:G$5+($A7=$D$2:$D$5)*$D$1*G$2:G$5)``` But I can't figure out how to subtract that percentage from the 100% assigned to the employee in B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
   = SUM(($B$2:$D$5=$A6)*$B$1:$D$1*E$2:E$5)
   - SUM( ($B$2:$B$5=$A6)*NOT(ISBLANK($C$2:$D$5))*($C$2:$D$5<>$A6)*E$2:E$5*$C$1:$D$1 )
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, you nailed it! For Dutch users: ```=SOM(($B$2:$D$5=$A6)*$B$1:$D$1*E$2:E$5)-SOM(($B$2:$B$5=$A6)*NIET(ISLEEG($C$2:$D$5))*($C$2:$D$5<>$A6)*E$2:E$5*$C$1:$D$1)```